# How to update a property of a JSON object

Tags: json, json.net

I've been trying to update JSON one of the value to a list of object.

snippet of code

```
public void updateJsonParameter(string file)
{
    try
    { 
        //   var jobject = file;

        //    Console.WriteLine("jobject value is "+ jobject[1]);

        // JsonConvert.PopulateObject(file, RootObject);
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(file);


        JObject jobject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(file) as JObject;
        JArray experiencesArrary = (JArray)jObject["ringValue"];         
    }
```

JSON format:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "jayatestdefid",
    "description": "test assignment through API",
    "metadata": {
      "assignedBy": "xyz@gmail.com"
    },
    "policyDefinitionId": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementgroups/MGTest/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/test",
    "parameters": {
      "ringValue": {
        "value": ["r0"]
      }
    },
    "enforcementMode": "DoNotEnforce",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to replace a value with a List in Json, you could create an instance of [JArray](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray__ctor_3.htm) and replace the require value. For example,

```
var list = new List<string>{"John Doe","Test Name"};
JArray array = new JArray(list);

var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
jObject["properties"]["displayName"]= array;
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject);
```

Output

```
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": [
      "John Doe",
      "Test Name"
    ],
    "description": "test assignment through API",
    "metadata": {
      "assignedBy": "xyz@gmail.com"
    },
    "policyDefinitionId": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementgroups/MGTest/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/test",
    "parameters": {
      "ringValue": {
        "value": [
          "r0"
        ]
      }
    },
    "enforcementMode": "DoNotEnforce"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the "put" method :

```
json.put("key", value);
```

the value can be a json array!

Comment: could you please give an example - are you saying something like below ? 

 var json = JObject.Parse(file);

 json.put("ringValue", "r0");

Comment: the "r0" could be a variable !! you can replace it with a jsonarray or whatever suits your example